# Android SQLite getting current date plus the last six days?

Tags: android, sql, date

I have an application that pulls information up by date but I want to get it so when the user pulls it up by the day it shows the last six days aswell. so far I have.

```
public double fetchInformation(){
        Date d = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat date= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String day = String.valueOf(date.format(d));
        Cursor c =  ourdb.rawQuery("SELECT*FROM " + WW_TABLE+" WHERE "+
        KEY_DATE+" LIKE  ?", new String[]{day});
        if(c.moveToFirst()){
            return c.getDouble(0);
        }
            return c.getDouble(0);
    }
```

how can I get that to give me the last six days from the current date?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to do something like this.

```
 Date d = new Date();

     Calendar last6Day= new GregorianCalendar() {{
          add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -6);
          set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
          set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
          set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
          set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        }};

    Date dt6 = last6Day.getTime();

    ourdb.rawQuery("SELECT*FROM tableName where date between dt6 AND dt");
```

Note: There may be syntax errors. I didn't type this in IDE.

Comment: Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Jan": syntax error: , while compiling: SELECT SUM(Time) FROM wwlltdTable WHERE Date BETWEEN Sat Jan 21 00:00:00 MST 2012 AND 2012-01-27 does it make a difference if I use `between` or `BETWEEN`? can I get i so that dt6 show up in `yyyy-mm-dd` format?

Comment: Between case is not issue, use simpledateformat to get in yyyy-mm-dd format.